# Collect stecific data from excel file to an other

Tags: java, xls, slk

i have a sylk file that i was trying to convert to xls, but in vain, i tried every possible way in java but it alwayse give me a file like pictures i shared[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ikyH.png).
so i want to extract the important data from that file and write it in an other xls file.

the algorithm is clean in my head but i dont know how to interpret it in java code.

i have a file .xls that has the data unorganised, but with the exact X,Y, i need to extract that data and put it in on other xls file with the X,Y of each information.

the data that i need alwayse exist in the line that starts with "C;"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN8TZ.png)

For example in the picture in row 128 i need as data B.C.E.A.O in the other xls file it needs to be in cell(1,2) as the Y right before it, is Y2 (Row 127), and the X (Row 126) right before it, is 1
i hope my request is pretty clear, i can add any more informations needed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.